# How can I write a VS Code keyboard shortcut to close the active workspace if it exists, and otherwise close the whole window?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I would like a keyboard shortcut configuration that does the following:

1. If a workspace folder is not opened, then close VS Code.
2. If a workspace folder is opened, then close the workspace folder. A second press would trigger action #1.

How can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean "if the current folder is opened"?

Comment: If the "current folder" is actually the workspace, I don't think this is possible in of itself because the workspace can contain multiple folders.

Answer (score 0):

See the "Global UI contexts" section of the [when-clause context docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts). There's a `workspaceFolderCount` when-clause that you can use. See also the sections on [operators](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#equality-operators).

```json
{
    "key": "<your-keybinding>",
    "when": "workspaceFolderCount > 0",
    "command": "workbench.action.closeFolder",
},
{
    "key": "<your-keybinding>",
    "when": "workspaceFolderCount == 0",
    "command": "workbench.action.quit", // or workbench.action.closeWindow
},
```

(I'm actually not sure what the difference between `workbench.action.quit` and `workbench.action.closeWindow` are).

Note: If you want to use <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, if you already have a default keybinding for <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> for the `workbench.action.quit` command, in which case I think you can just keep that and don't need to write one again.

Comment: The `workbench.action.closeFolder` command closes the entire workspace.  Which may be what the OP wants.  But if there are multiple workspaceFolders in a workspace, they are All closed (which is probably okay but should be pointed out).  Maybe "active workspace" refers to one folder at a time...